# how to write data to text file using batch

Tags: batch-file, echo

I have create the batch file with following code

```
echo. > Statgather.txt
echo set headING oN; > statgather.txt
echo spool br.txt >> statgather.txt
echo set headING off; >> statgather.txt
echo select * from branchseats where branchcode = '&BRANCHCODE'; >> statgather.txt
echo. >> Statgather.txt
echo spool off; >> statgather.txt
echo quit Statgather.txt
```

But the results was come like below

```
set headING oN; 

spool br.txt 
set headING off;  
spool off;
```

Please help me to create a batch file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, *before asking in future, please search the site*.

```bat
(Echo Line 1
 Echo Line 2
 Echo Line 3
 Echo Line 4)>"Statgather.txt"
```

*Some characters, especially ampersands, redirection characters and closing parentheses, may need escaping*.

Comment: thank you  for a comment . but under mentioned line not appear in "Statgather.txt"
select * from branchseats where branchcode = '&BRANCHCODE';

Comment: @akila, did you read the footnote? _do you know what an ampersand is?_